# Using where in custom model validation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, model, customvalidator

Platform: Rail 3.0
Database: mysql 5.1

Business requirement: Only one item of a product can be issued at a time. After a return of the issued item, a new item can be issued of same product. Multiple items from different products can be issued at a time.

To implement the above business requirement, I am checking if there is already an item issued for the same product within the same date range (by checking to see if there is an overlap of the dates in my `where` below).

However, I am getting the following exception: **NoMethodError: undefined method `where' for Lecture:Module**.

I need to be able to use my custom validation to enforce this business requirement. Any ideas? The below is what I have so far:

```
class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
  validate :validate_one_item_for_product
  def validate_one_item_for_product
    items = Item.where( "issue_date < ? and return_date > ? and product_id = ?",
                        return_date,
                        issue_date,
                        product_id)
    errors.add( :base,
                "item already issued for this product, not returned yet") if items.size > 0
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normally `Item.where` would work, but for some reason in this case it seems to be having namespacing issues.

`self.class.where` should be fine.

Comment: Item.where also not working, i tried it before trying this one. I worked these queries on rails console, but it is not working in inside of Model function. Am i missing some basics concepts?

Comment: Here is exception i am getting in case of Item.where NoMethodError: undefined method `where' for Item:Module

Comment: I tried it and it worked fine in my Rails project. Strange! Must be some weird namespacing going on. Try self.class.where and let me know if you have any luck!

Comment: self.class.where is working. any ideas why not Item.where    I am not able to upvote (downvoted earlier). edit ur answer then i can upvote.

Thanks you.

Comment: That's good. No I don't know why Item.where isn't working, sorry.